# Problems with windows user account permissions

Tags: permissions, directory

Inherited the maintenance of an existing ASP.net (C#) web based system. It is running on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.

PDF files are generated via a background process - Omniformat. It runs as a scheduled task and creates PDF files from html files. For some reason it doesn't inherit the permissions of the folder that it is in, or from thethe html file it was generated from. This means that web users can not access the files.

Can anyone help me out please? Is there a way to force a created file to inherit the permissions of the folder it is in?

Many thanks.

Comment: if you look in the processes what user is Omniformat running under?

Answer (score 0):

The file should do that automatically, unless the OmniFormat is creating the files somewhere else, like say a temp folder they moving the files into place.  The solution would be to either change the rights to the temp folder, or add a step to the process so that after the files are created to reset the rights.

Comment: It doesn't appear to create the files in a temporary folder unfortunately

Comment: How are the permissions being created?  What account is the omniformat app running under?